# No sound coming from the amplifier

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I just got my new guitar and amplifier, and after the unboxing I plugged them both for a test! Everything was working fine, I turned the amplifier off and moved them to my room.
On the next try, the sound didn't come out from the amplifier!
I tried another cable but the issue remains the same.

Any help?

Comment: What kind of amp? What kind of guitar?

Comment: My guitar is (Epiphone Les Paul Special VE) and the amplifier is (sawtooth 10W) the amplifier turns on but there's no sound

Comment: Did you try moving the amp back to the room it was working in the first time?

Answer (score 2):

Some of these may seem obvious, but here are some troubleshooting steps:

1. Does it turn on? If not is it plugged in? If so does the power outlet that you're using work with other things? If not try a different outlet.
2. If it's turned on, is the speaker plugged in? You didn't mention the amp model, but even on combo amps there's frequently a cable in the back that needs to connect from the amp to the speaker.
3. If the speaker is plugged in, is the volume knob(s) (you may have channel/gain knob *and* a master volume depending on the amp) turned up?
4. If the volume is turned up, is there some kind of FX loop that is switched on? If so you may need to turn it off.
5. Is your guitar volume turned up? Maybe even try unplugging the guitar and just touching the end of the cable with your thumb. Does it make a buzzing noise when you touch it? If so then it's something with your guitar and not the amp.

Comment: I tried unplugging the guitar and touching the end of the cable with my thumb, and the amplifier didn't make any sound!

Comment: Ok, how about the other 4 things?

Comment: The amplifier turns on, the model is (sawtooth 10W) so there's no speak cable! All the knops are at the middle level (volume, gain, treble, middle, bass) there's a drive select and its switched off.

Comment: Try plugging in headphones to see if you hear anything from there. Even if you don't, try plugging and unplugging a cable from the headphone jack a couple times. Sometimes headphone jacks can get stuck where it thinks a cable is plugged in (and thus the speaker is turned off) even when one isn't.

Comment: My headphones plug is much smaller than the amplifier!! I guess i need a different cable or extinction?

Comment: Yes, you need [something like this](https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-107139-6-35mm-Stereo-Adaptor/dp/B005E2Y0KK/). It's also a very cheap (inexpensive) amp so I wouldn't rule out something being defective.

Comment: Do you hear anything if you turn the volumn all the up? Hiss, hum?

Comment: No nothing at all! The weird thing is i actually bought two guitars and two of the same amplifiers, and both of them didn't work the second time!

Comment: What kind of power do wall outlet give in your area ? It might be relevant since the amp seem to be quite cheap in conception and it specifies on the website that this kind of amp requires 120VAC. If you gave it more power you might have burned something

Comment: wondering if it has a fuse? also, did the OP turn the amp off before unplugging it from the wall?